# Outlook auto-complete list doesn’t remember names or email addresses

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, autocomplete, address-book

I have MS Outlook 2010, but the Auto-Complete list doesn’t remember names or email addresses. It remembers them for the first time before I close and open Outlook again. When I open Outlook it seems clears all previous Auto-Complete list.  I tried the details [written here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/the-auto-complete-list-doesnt-remember-names-or-email-addresses-HA102534585.aspx), but no benefit.